# TSC keeps creating subfolders in the 'outDir'

Tags: json, typescript, tsc, tsconfig

**Hi there!**

I am working on a small project with TypeScript which requires me to have two different `tsconfig.json` files which both inherit from my `tsconfig.base.json` file.

I ran into the problem of the compiler creating subfolders in my declared `outDir` which kinda drives me insane.

Here is my `tsconfig.base.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
      "esModuleInterop": true,
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

and this is what the derived `tsconfig.src.json` looks like:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDirs": ["./src/ts", "."],
        "outDir": "./src/js/"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "page/**/*.ts",
        "tsconfig.page.json"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "service_account.json"
    ],
}
```

My current project structure looks like this:

```
.
+-- node_modules/
+-- src/
|    +-- js/ (this is where my typescript files should be compiled to)
|    +-- ts/ (this is where all my ts files are located)
+-- tsconfig.base.json
+-- tsconfig.src.json
+-- service_account.json
```

Now if I run my `build:backend` script (`"build:backend": "tsc -p ./tsconfig.source.json"`) the compiler creates two subfolders which makes my project structure look like this:

```
.
+-- node_modules/
+-- src/
|    +-- js/ (this is where my typescript files should be compiled to)
|        +-- src/
|            +-- ts/ (here are all compiled js files now)
|    +-- ts/ (this is where all my ts files are located)
+-- tsconfig.base.json
+-- tsconfig.src.json
+-- service_account.json
```

Does anybody have an idea what causes this problem?

I am thankful for every kind of help! Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to consolidate all `inputs` into a single folder and all `outputs` into a folder *that is not included* in the `inputs` folder.

## Example fix

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "/src/ts",
        "outDir": "./src/js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "page/**/*.ts",
        "tsconfig.page.json"
    ]
}
```

And move `service_account.json` into `src/ts` as well.